# Accessing block properties

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I get access the value of [insertedItem objectForKey:@"id"] from outside of the block?

```
   [itemTable insert:item completion:^(NSDictionary *insertedItem, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Item inserted, id: %@", [insertedItem objectForKey:@"id"]);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Think of blocks as anonymous methods. Can you access a method's local variables from outside? No.

If you want, you can save the value in another variable and access it:

```
[itemTable insert:item completion:^(NSDictionary *insertedItem, NSError *error) {
   self.insertedItem = insertedItem;
}];
```

Obviously, make sure insertedItem is a `strong` reference.

Comment: If you’re referencing self inside the block, don’t you need to make a weak reference to self?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg only if `self` also has a strong reference to to the block, we can't tell from this code fragment if it does or not.

Comment: Using this approach, you'll never know when the block has been processed (perhaps on another thread in 3 minutes?), so you need to add a delegate or NSNotification to listen to the `self.insertedItem` being changed.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer Well, seeing as this is a *completion block*, I think OP is already covered on that.